# Best way to upload any type of data to server?

Tags: android

My question is that what is the best way to upload data to the server. The twist is that when the device is offline then it stores the data anywhere and when the device will online then auto get the data and upload to the server...

Comment: did you search google ? i think thats easier than posting a question ..

Comment: @SantanuSur, yes but I could not find the best way. Can u guide me?

Comment: you can try sync adapter...or you can go with 672009's answer.. for sync adapter https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html check this out

Comment: @SantanuSur Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to achieve what you want. But the simplest way is probably using Firebase. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Implement three task.

1)  if internet is available 
--> upload data to server via Retrofit library

```
reference URL:- [http://square.github.io/retrofit/][1]
```

2) if internet is not available
--> save all data during offline into SQLite database

```
reference URL:- [https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/][1]
```

3) Create broadcast receiver for internet on/off state event listener

--> reference URL:- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/
when internet on status state receive you need to send all data that is saved in SQLite database to server and delete that data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Upload on android knows to be a little tedious. I would recommend [gotev/android-upload-service](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service). Which supports bunch of features and covers most of the use cases